# How to retrieve id of newly added row in custom code event in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, chronoforms

i'm new in joomla and i'm trying to get the id of newly inserted record in URL by custom code event.

Comment: Your question is woefully light on details.  Please show more context and effort.  When you have a Joomla question, please feed the community at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ChronoForms then the record ID will be in the form data. You can use a Debugger action to see exactly where it is saved. It will depend on which version of ChronoForms you are using.

Comment: ...fyi http://greyhead.net/ is offline.  Also, if you are a Joomla user, perhaps you could create a [joomla.se] Stack Exchange account and help to resolve some questions over there.